# Is there a way to combine multiple search functions into a dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple search functions/text boxes that I would like to condense into a textbox + dropdown selection.

http://jsfiddle.net/rhnt9vme/3/

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input type='text' id='searchOneInput' />
    <button type='submit' onclick='searchOne()' target="_blank">Search 1</button>
  </form>
</div><br>

<div>
  <form>
    <input type='text' id='searchTwoInput' />
    <button type='submit' onclick='searchTwo()' target="_blank">Search 2</button>
  </form>
</div><br>

<div>
  <form>
    <input type='text' id='searchThreeInput' />
    <button type='submit' onclick='searchThree()' target="_blank">Search 3</button>
  </form>
</div><br>

function searchOne(){
    var searchOneInput = document.getElementById('searchOneInput').value;
    window.open("http://one.com/search=" + searchOneInput);
}

function searchTwo(){
    var searchTwoInput = document.getElementById('searchTwoInput').value;
    window.open("http://two.com/search=" + searchTwoInput);
}

function searchThree(){
    var searchThreeInput = document.getElementById('searchThreeInput').value;
    window.open("http://three.com/search=" + searchThreeInput);
}
```

I want to combine these into a dropdown selection single textbox search that looks like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" id="userInput" />
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">Search 1</option>
    <option value="">Search 2</option>
    <option value="">Search 3</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit" onclick="">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set an ID to your form and listen for `"submit"` event using [`Element.addEventListener()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- Set the respective websites URL inside the `<option>`s `value` attribute
- Don't forget to [trim the user input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), just in case of accidental wrapping whitespaces

```js
document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // Comment out if not needed
  
  var dropdownURL = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
  var searchInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value.trim();
  var address = dropdownURL + searchInput;
  
  console.log(address);
  window.open(address);
});
```

```html
<form id="searchForm">  <!-- PS: add ID to form -->
  <input type="text" id="userInput">
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="http://one.com/?search=">Search 1</option>
    <option value="http://two.com/?search=">Search 2</option>
    <option value="http://three.com/?search=">Search 3</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

In case you need a *combined* **URI** string with additional suffixed query parameters like

> https://example.com/?search=**USERINPUTHERE**&c=%2FDefault.asp

than you could use a placeholder in the set of [not URI allowed characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), like `|`, and replace it with the user input string using [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
document.getElementById("searchForm").addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // Comment out if not needed
  
  var dropdownURL = document.getElementById("dropdown").value;
  var searchInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value.trim();
  
  // Replace "|" with the user input
  var address = dropdownURL.replace(/\|/, searchInput);
  
  console.log(address);
  window.open(address);
});
```

```html
<form id="searchForm">  <!-- PS: add ID to form -->
  <input type="text" id="userInput">
  <select id="dropdown">
    <option value="http://one.com/?search=|">Search 1</option>
    <option value="http://two.com/?search=|">Search 2</option>
    <option value="http://three.com/?search=|">Search 3</option>
    <option value="https://four.com/?search=|&c=%2FDefault.asp">Search 4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

PS: since the order of *query params* is not important, you can always define your string like: `https://example.com/?c=%2FDefault.asp&search=` and use the first example anyways.

Comment: Perfect! What if I had a URL like this though:

`function searchInput(){
    var searchInput= document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
    window.open("https://four.com/?search=" + userInput+ "&c=%2FDefault.asp");
}`

Comment: @DMo take a look, hope it helps. The `|` character will be replaced with the users input value. The `|` is safe to use since is not allowed in URI strings: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-2

Comment: @DMo but, since the order of query params is not important, you can always define your string like: `https://four.com/?c=%2FDefault.asp&search=` and use the first example anyways.

Comment: Thanks so much. On both examples I am seeing this error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @DMo That's because you did not read my answer enough ;) :D It's stated in a couple of places. You need to add the ID to the form like I did. Your `<form>` has no ID, therefore the `null`. Or you misspelled it. Anyways... hope you'll make it work on your end